# What organization to call when find a hurt wild bird as a tourist in Copenhagen?

Tags: copenhagen

#### Context

I have recently visited Copenhagen (Denmark) and while visiting the Little Mermaid my wife noticed a sort of wild goose with a broken leg. It could not fly, so I tried to quickly search for a local organization that might help the bird.

In the meantime, a young couple managed to make a call and they were promised that someone will come in about one hour. After one hour, a man came, took a quick look at the bird, took it with a special net and made a cutthroat sign, while mentioning something about bird flu and thanking about the notification.

Any questions were left unanswered since none of us knew Danish and the guy did not know English.

The guy came with a red car having the name "Falk" which had a falcon icon on it. I could not find anything about this but also noticed the name in the airport, somewhat related to maintenance or similar.

#### Question

This made me think that the call was not done to the appropriate authority/organization. I am not exactly sure, but the young couple most like called one of the following:

- Dyrenes Beskyttelse (The Danish Animal Protection):

Website: https://www.dyrenesbeskyttelse.dk/
Phone: +45 33 28 39 99

- Dyrenes Vagtcentral (Animal Emergency Hotline):

Phone: 1812

Is there a better alternative? By better, I mean some organization that favors treatment rather than euthanasia for such cases.

Comment: Why do you assume the person/organisation _doesn't_ favour treatment? It could be that in this specific case treatment wasn't possible/practicable.

Comment: I assumed this due to the fact that the bird was taken in a hurry + the "cutthroat sign". Unfortunately, I have seen only in documentaries how a bird is rescued and I might have a romanticized view about the process.

Comment: Bird flu has, unfortunately, also altered the way that animals can be treated - there are currently legal restrictions on how wild birds are dealt with which any rescue charity must deal with in operation in many countries.

Comment: The man who arrived may have been working for "Falck" which is a company providing ambulance services, firefigthing services, roadside assistance, animal ambulance among other services.